# Programmatically Select AngularJS Typeahead Option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a AngularJS Typeahead that retrieves matches asynchronously. When a barcode is scanned into the field, it returns the matching result, but the user still has to select it. I would like to automatically select the result if it's an exact match. I see that the typeahead has a select(idx) function, but am not sure how to get a reference to it from my controller.

I was envisioning something like this:

```
$scope.SearchItems = function (term) {
    return $http.get('api/Items/Search', {
        params: {
            term: term
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.length == 1 && response.data[0].Code == term) {
            // Somehow inform typeahead control to select response.data[0]
        }
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you please add a console.log(response) and let me know what it returns?

Comment: { 
    config: {...},
    data: [{ Code = "ABC", OtherProperties = Values }],
    status: 200,
    statusText: "OK"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and never figured how to access the typeahead's `select(idx)`, but I managed to get this functionality working. Here's my hacky workaround....

```
$promise.then(function(res) {
 angular.forEach(res, function(item, key) {

     // if we have an exact match
     if (item.title === term) {
         // update model
         $scope.src = item;

         // find item in dropdown
         var elm = '[id*=option-' + key + ']';
         var opt = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(elm));

         //call click handler outside of digest loop
         $timeout(function() {
             opt.triggerHandler('click');
         }, 0);
     }
 });
 // return async results
 return res;
});
```

Basically we just update our model manually, locate the element in our dropdown and then fire off the 'click' handler. Make sure you wrap the `triggerHandler` call in a `$timeout()` set to zero, otherwise you will get a `$rootScope:inprog` error since digest is already in progress.

Comment: This will work if there is only one typeahead on the page, correct? If you have multiple it will attempt to select that index on each typeahead.

Comment: Yes this is correct, but from what I understand, the typeahead options are only visible if the typeahead is being used.... so if you had multiple typeaheads, it would only be selecting the visible option.